# Chaining iterators of different types

Tags: iterator, rust

I get type errors when chaining different types of Iterator.

```
let s = Some(10);
let v = (1..5).chain(s.iter())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Output:

```
<anon>:23:20: 23:35 error: type mismatch resolving `<core::option::Iter<'_, _> as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == _`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found integral variable [E0271]
<anon>:23     let v = (1..5).chain(s.iter())
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:23:20: 23:35 help: see the detailed explanation for E0271
<anon>:24:14: 24:33 error: no method named `collect` found for type `core::iter::Chain<core::ops::Range<_>, core::option::Iter<'_, _>>` in the current scope
<anon>:24             .collect::<Vec<_>>();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:24:14: 24:33 note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `core::iter::Chain<core::ops::Range<_>, core::option::Iter<'_, _>> : core::iter::Iterator`
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

But it works fine when zipping:

```
let s = Some(10);
let v = (1..5).zip(s.iter())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Output:

```
[(1, 10)]
```

Why is Rust able to infer the correct types for `zip` but not for `chain` and how can I fix it? n.b. I want to be able to do this for any iterator, so I don't want a solution that just works for Range and Option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that the iterators yield different types. I've added an explicit `u8` to the numbers to make the types more obvious:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Some(10u8);
    let r = (1..5u8);

    let () = s.iter().next(); // Option<&u8>
    let () = r.next();        // Option<u8>
}
```

When you `chain` two iterators, **both iterators must yield the same type**. This makes sense as the iterator cannot "switch" what type it outputs when it gets to the end of one and begins on the second:

```
fn chain<U>(self, other: U) -> Chain<Self, U::IntoIter> 
    where U: IntoIterator<Item=Self::Item>
//                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ This means the types must match
```

So why does `zip` work? Because it doesn't have that restriction:

```
fn zip<U>(self, other: U) -> Zip<Self, U::IntoIter> 
    where U: IntoIterator
//                       ^~~~ Nothing here!
```

This is because `zip` returns a tuple with one value from each iterator; a new type, distinct from either source iterator's type. One iterator could be an integral type and the other could return your own custom type for all `zip` cares.

> Why is Rust able to infer the correct types for `zip` but not for `chain`

There is no type inference happening here; that's a different thing. This is just plain-old type mismatching.

> and how can I fix it?

In this case, your inner iterator yields a reference to an integer, a `Clone`-able type, so you can use [`cloned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) to make a new iterator that clones each value and then both iterators would have the same type:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Some(10);
    let v: Vec<_> = (1..5).chain(s.iter().cloned()).collect();
}
```

If you are done with the option, you can also use a *consuming iterator* with `into_iter`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Some(10);
    let v: Vec<_> = (1..5).chain(s.into_iter()).collect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. What do you think is the performance impact of cloning here? I am wondering whether it is worth chaining in such cases.

Comment: The performance impact is very likely to be completely negligible here. Cloning a integer is a simple bitwise copy and that's a thing computers do ^_^. I've added another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. The question is generic, though. I do not know how cloning works in Rust; just seeing an extra cost in general. The alternative with `into_iter` looks good---having a look at the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great. I didn't even spot that that `&`. Now I need to find out why `Option` works differently in this case..

Comment: What happens is the Item of both iterators are of different types but implement the same Trait? Can you join them returning an Iterator over elements of that shared Trait?

Comment: @Hernan you would have to map them to Box<Trait>